# StackOverflowError with Hibernate when trying to implement JWT Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, lombok

I am new to this topic and I keep getting "java.lang.StackOverflowError: null" When I try and authorize. I get Internal server error in postman and in the console I get the stackoveflowerror.
This is my AuthenticationController:

```
   @PostMapping("/signup")
   public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
       if (userService.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
           throw new BadRequestException("email already exists");
       }
       User user = UserMapper.INSTANCE.registerRequestoUser(signUpRequest);
       user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
       Optional<Role> optionalRole = roleService.getByName("user");

       if (optionalRole.isPresent()) {
           Role userRole = optionalRole.get();
           user.addRole(userRole);
           Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.create(user);
           if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
               User result = optionalUser.get();
               URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                       .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/v1/users/email/{email}")
                       .buildAndExpand(result.getEmail()).toUri();

               return ResponseEntity.created(location).body("User registered successfully");
           }

       }
       return (ResponseEntity<?>) ResponseEntity.badRequest();
   }
```

My SignUpRequest class:

```
public class SignUpRequest {
   @NotBlank
   private String firstName;

   @NotBlank
   private String lastName;

   @NotBlank
   @Email
   private String email;

   @NotBlank
   @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
   private String password;

   private Set<String> roles;
```

My user entity and my role entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 100, message
            = "password must be between 3 and 50 characters")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Appointment> appointments;


    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

    public String  getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

And here is my postman request

```
{
        "firstName":"name",
        "lastName":"name",
        "email": "an@gmail.com",
        "password": "thepassword123",
        "roles": ["user"]

}
```

Here is a piece from the stack trace:

```
at at com.project.rushhour.entity.User.hashCode(User.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
...
at at com.project.rushhour.entity.Role.hashCode(Role.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
...


at com.project.rushhour.entity.User.hashCode(User.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
...
at com.project.rushhour.entity.Role.hashCode(Role.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
...


at com.project.rushhour.entity.User.hashCode(User.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
...
at com.project.rushhour.entity.Role.hashCode(Role.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

I think the error is somewhere around when the program is trying to parse the roles, but not sure exactly what is the problem. The things for jwt are set up correctly, it's just the logic that is wrong

Comment: Hi, this is the full exception https://pastebin.com/tU92bnKP It is quite long

Comment: Show your stack trace. It should be a part of the question. Don't use any external resources.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: No :) That is not correct. Normally there are very few lines that a repeated many times. Often these are about 15-20 lines. So pasting 15-20 lines would be absolutely sufficient.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I have added a repeating part of stack trace. As you see, it takes not so much place :)

Comment: @mkashi: You didn't show any effort to analyze the stack trace actually your question should have been downvoted. But I like that your question is about **StackOverflowError** - this is the name of this site. So I voted your question up :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the problem is, that you have relations from *User* to *Role* and from *Role* to user. But you have not explicitly defined *hashCode* method. You use *@Data* annotation. By default Lombok generates *hashCode* method that includes *all* the properties of the entity.

*hashCode* is normally calculated as follows:

```
h = hashCode(property1);
h = h*31 + hashCode(property2);
h = h*31 + hashCode(property3);
h = h*31 + hashCode(property4);
h = h*31 + hashCode(property5);
...
```

When *hashCode* is called on *User*, if calculates hash codes of properties *firstName*, *lastName*, etc. Then also add the hash code of the property *roles*. Calculation of hash code of *roles* includes calculation of hash code of every *Role* element.

But calculation of hash code *Role* includes calculation of hash code of the property *users*, which calls hashCode() on every *User* element. And as we see above, hash code of *User* will again coll hash code of *Role*. etc. Until the stack capacity is used. Then you get *StackOverflowError*.

How can you avoid it? Exclude recursion from *hashCode()* method. Either implement hashCode() manually. Or tell Lombok to exclude relation based properties from *hashCode()*.

I would prefer that Lombok still generates everything for me. So I would tell Lombok to ignore property *roles* in the *User* entity and property *users* in the *Role* entity when generating *hashCode()* and *equals()*. So your code would look as follows:

```
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    ...
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> roles;

    ...
}

public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    ...    
    private String name;

    ...
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> users;

    ...

}
```

Why is annotation called *EqualsAndHashCode*? Because *hashCode()* and *equals()* should always be changed *synchronously* to fulfill so called *hashCode - equals* contract.